# Android MapView Initial Location

Tags: android, android-mapview

My app currently starts detecting its location as soon as it launches however when I load up a MapActivity some time later it takes a while before MyLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix is fired.

Am I able to somehow pass the location I already have to the map when it is initially created?

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to believe that your runOnFirst fix is taking a long time to run as if you already have an active location listener or had one recently it should get a location pretty quickly:

[runOnFirstFix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay#runOnFirstFix%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

> Queues a runnable to be executed as soon as we have a location fix. If
>   we already have a fix, we'll execute the runnable immediately and
>   return true. If not, we'll hang on to the runnable and return false;
>   as soon as we get a location fix, we'll run it in in a new thread.